# Elementor - Query for Redirect - Email?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Would really appreciate some help with this one!

I have an Elementor Form that redirects to a second opt in page, and would like all of the information to be passed through..

I've managed to achieve this for First Name & Last Name, but it doesn't work for email...

- Here's the query I use for redirecting that works: example.com/?fname=[field id="fname"]&lname=[field id="lname"]
- If I use: example.com/?fname=[field id="fname"]&lname=[field id="lname"]&email=[field id=“email”] Elementor won't redirect the page

Maybe passing the data through is a privacy issue or maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

try to rename email to cemail, like this

example.com/?fname=[field id="fname"]&lname=[field id="lname"]&cemail=[field id=“cemail”]

dont forget to update email id to cemail.